# How to replace 'Underscore' by 'without space' in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

How can I replace the following strings

- "Assigned_To" into "AssignedTo"
- "Assigned_To_You" into "AssignedToYou"

By C#.NET

Comment: Have you tried [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, String.Replace "_" with String.Empty (or "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str = "Assigned_To_You".Replace("_", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`String.Replace("_","");`
it will replace every underscore by nothing.

**String** means every object of string type.

Comment: It's an endless debate, but consider using String.Empty instead of "". I find it more expressive and slightly more efficient

Comment: Yeah you right.But i think that CLR translation will do it's work in this way and "" is more readable for me. As you pointed out, it's endless debate.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Assigned_To".replace("_", "");
```